# Links to external site in canvas tab on facebook page show up within canvas instead of redirecting to new page

Tags: facebook, iframe, canvas, tabs, hyperlink

I'm on a bit of a deadline and I'm having a problem with the canvas app I designed as a tab on my facebook page.

Using Dreamweaver to create the canvas I have set pictures that link to external websites. Unfortunately, when you click on the linking pictures, the websites are loaded within the canvas area on facebook. I would like them to redirect the entire page to the website link.

Forgive me if this is a ridiculous question, I'm rather new at this whole thing.

**UPDATE** Okay, figured it out. To anyone who's just starting out like me, all you have to do to have it redirect to a new page is put `target="_top"></a>` just at the end of your link in the webpage code.

Comment: You should answer your question with this `target="_top"` tip. It helped me out of a pickle!