# Clickable external links inside facebook canvas app

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, hyperlink, facebook-canvas

I have links inside facebook canvas application. And when users click it, it should show in new tab or page. How to do that?

I use javascript `location` to redirect user to facebook login page.

I saw a code some months that is in javascript by a user in stackoverflow posted as a solution for this but I searched for two days and didn't find it.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer you're looking for is in the link below. In essence, a href="xyz" **target="_top"** and so: **window.top.location=xyz**

[window.top.location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332756/difference-between-window-location-href-and-top-location-href)

[links-to-external-site-in-canvas-tab-on-facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455718/links-to-external-site-in-canvas-tab-on-facebook-page-show-up-within-canvas-inst)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the link in new tab

```
        window.open(urlOfNewPage);
```

If you want to open the link in same window

```
        window.location = urlOfNewPage;
```